# Substituição de valores em uma lista

Tags: python

Preciso substituir valores em uma lista de acordos com alguns critérios.

Critérios:

1. se o valor for um número inteiro e  menor que o valor informado substituir por -1
2. se o valor for um número  em ponto flutuante e maior que o numero informado substituir por 9999.0.

Código:

```
lista =[-9 ,20.5, 6 ,10.8, 10, 8.0, 45, -99.6, 12, -54.7]
valores = input('Digite um valor inteiro e um valor em ponto   flutuante:').split()
num1 = int((valores[0]))
num2 = float((valores[1]))
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if int(num1):
        if lista[i] < num1:
            lista[i]= -1
    if float(num2):
        if lista[i] > num2:
            lista[i] =9999.0

print(lista)
```

Saida correta seria:

```
-1 9999.0 -1 9999.0 10 8.0 45 -99.6 12 -54.7
```

A saida do meu código está:

```
-1, 9999.0, -1, 9999.0, 9999.0, -1, 9999.0, -1, 9999.0, -1
```

Amigos consegui resolver da seguinte forma.

Código:

```
 lista =[-9 ,20.5, 6 ,10.8, 10, 8.0, 45, -99.6, 12, -54.7]
 valores = input('Digite um valor inteiro e um valor em ponto   flutuante:').split()
 num1 = int((valores[0]))
 num2 = float((valores[1]))
 for i in range(len(lista)):
    if type(lista[i]) is int and lista[i] < num1:
       lista[i] = -1
    elif type(lista[i]) is float and lista[i] > num2:
       lista[i] = 9999.0
 print(lista)
```

Comment: Escusas de fazer os ifs `float` e `int`, já o são quando recebes o input e fazes cast para esses tipos. Estás com `9999` no código mas na explicação/resultados dizes `999`, deve ser gralha/engano.

Comment: Miguel, já corrigi o erro na verdade é 9999.0.

Comment: Não vejo nada que funcione mal, talvez queiras só um `elif(...)` em vez do segundo `if`, https://ideone.com/MVnftr , para que não entre nos dois `ifs` porque nesse caso o segundo `if` vai prevalecer mesmo que o primeiro se verifique

Comment: Olá Miguel, o codigo não está dando a saida correta, tentei com elif mas não funcionou, mas obrigado por participar, vou pra luta.

Comment: Agradeço  a todos .

Comment: @Bruno Só comentando, não é recomendado utilizar o `type` para verificar o tipo, pois ele não verifica herança. Como no Python a tipagem é dinâmica, esse é um detalhe que deve ser sempre levado em conta. Use `isinstance` para tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um pouco mais simplificado que sua solução

```
lista =[-9 ,20.5, 6 ,10.8, 10, 8.0, 45, -99.6, 12, -54.7]
valor_inteiro, valor_float = [float(x) for x in input('Digite um valor 
inteiro e um valor em ponto flutuante:').split()]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if isinstance(lista[i], int) and lista[i] < valor_inteiro:
        lista[i] = -1
    if isinstance(lista[i], float) and lista[i] > valor_float:
        lista[i] = 9999.0

print(lista)
```

Comment: Obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss, me ajudou muito esse ensinamento.